# How to update the saleable quantity after invoice creation in magento2

Tags: magento2, product, invoice, sales

Normally the saleable quantity is updatd after when we place the order. I want to update the saleable quantity after invoice creation for my custom producttype..

Answer (score 0):

Just a solution from the top of my head - create shipment automatically after invoice creation for this specific product type.
If I understand correctly - you assume that the product was shipped and is no longer in your warehouse; this solution should work fine for your needs.